# How to use cURL in ASP.NET with Cookie File

Tags: asp.net, curl, cookies

I am using an Hardware Device and want to do some operation on it.

Presently it uses cURL to do the operations. But I want to do the same in ASP.NET web form application, given bellow are the CURL Commands that the device use:

1) First I have to store the User Authentication in a cookie file:

```
curl -1 -v -L -k -c cookie.txt  -d save=2 -d adm_name=admin -d adm_pwd=admin  https://10.71.1.111/check.shtml
```

This store `cookie.txt` in my folder.

2) Now I have to run the second command to do the main operation (Create User in this case)

```
curl -1 -v -L -k -b cookie.txt -d save=1 -d U1=michael -d P1=abcd1234 -d M1=00:09:6B:CD:88:00 -d C1=d -d R1=FinanceDep https:// 10.71.1.111/UserAuthentication/AddUser.shtml
```

Here I am sending the `cookie.txt` file to create the user. In this command `U1`, `P1`, `M1`, `C1`, `R1` are the parameters.

Can anyone help me to do the same from ASP.NET

Regards
Santanu

**EDIT:**

On basis of the Answer given I converted the code in VB.NET and used it, but unfortunately its nor giving any error and in returning anything in responce

Dim jar As New CookieContainer()

```
        Dim target As New Uri("https://x.x.x.x/check.shtml")

        'jar.Add(New Cookie("adm", "admin"))
        'jar.Add(New Cookie("admpwd", "6e49b5b6c16eff37c0d8217382fe1c7e"))
        'jar.Add(New Cookie("first_login_home_page", "home.shtml"))
        'jar.Add(New Cookie("name", "value"))

        jar.Add(New Uri("https://x.x.x.x/check.shtml"), New Cookie("adm", "admin"))
        jar.Add(New Uri("https://x.x.x.x/check.shtml"), New Cookie("admpwd", "6e49b5b6c16eff37c0d8217382fe1c7e"))
        jar.Add(New Uri("https://x.x.x.x/check.shtml"), New Cookie("first_login_home_page", "home.shtml"))

        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create("https://x.x.x.x/UserAuthentication/AddUser.shtml"), HttpWebRequest)

        request.CookieContainer = jar
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = True
        ' request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = AddressOf AcceptAllCertifications

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(Function() True)


        request.Method = "POST"

        Dim fields As New NameValueCollection()
        fields.Add("save", "1")
        fields.Add("U1", "michael")
        fields.Add("P1", "abcd1234")
        fields.Add("C1", "1")
        fields.Add("R1", "FinanceDep")



        Using requestBody As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            Using wtr As New StreamWriter(requestBody, Encoding.ASCII)
                Dim first As [Boolean] = True
                For Each key As [String] In fields.Keys
                    If Not first Then
                        wtr.Write("&"c)
                    End If
                    Dim keyEnc As [String] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(key)
                    Dim valEnc As [String] = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(fields(key))

                    wtr.Write(keyEnc)
                    wtr.Write("="c)
                    wtr.Write(valEnc)
                    first = False
                Next
            End Using
        End Using


        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing

        Try
            response = request.GetResponse()
        Catch wex As WebException
            If wex.Response IsNot Nothing Then
                response = wex.Response
            End If
        End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

For making HTTP requests, .NET has three options:

- `HttpWebRequest` - a simple single-request/response with a blocking API.
- `HttpClient`- introduced in .NET 4, has an `async` API.
- `WebClient` - a stateful wrapper around `HttpWebRequest`. I don't recommend using it.

My personal preference is to use `HttpWebRequest` because I find handling async calls in cases where blocking-calls are fine to be ugly, and also for its relative simplicitly:

Your curl options are:

```
-1     Force TLS
-v     Verbose
-L     Follow HTTP Location: header in redirections
-k     Disables TLS certificate CA checking
-c     Specify cookie jar file
-d     Specify request body form fields and use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
```

This can be converted to `HttpWebRequest` like so:

```
CookieContainer jar = new CookieContainer();
jar.Add( new Cookie("name", "value") );

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://10.71.1.111/check.shtml");
request.CookieContainer = jar;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate(sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) {
    return true; // ignore all certificate errors
};
request.Method = "POST";

NameValueCollection fields = new NameValueCollection();
fields.Add("save", "2");
fields.Add("adm_name", "admin");
fields.Add("adm_pwd", "admin");
fields.Add("U1", "michael");

// Set request body
using(Stream requestBody = request.GetRequestStream())
using(StreamWriter wtr = new StreamWriter( requestBody, Encoding.ASCII ) ) {
    Boolean first = true;
    foreach(String key in fields.Keys) {
        if( !first ) wtr.Write('&');
        String keyEnc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( key );
        String valEnc = HttpUtility.UrlEncode( fields[key] );

        wtr.Write( keyEnc );
        wtr.Write('=');
        wtr.Write( valEnc );
        first = false;
    }
}

HttpWebResponse response = null;
try {
    response = request.GetResponse();
} catch(WebException wex) {
    if( wex.Response != null ) response = wex.Response;
}

// do stuff with response
```

Note that the `-1` option does not apply as `HttpWebRequest` will use the systemwide TLS settings, and as it's connecting using the `https://` scheme it won't fallback to plain HTTP.

I see you're using a cookie-file that exists on the filesystem. You'll need to put the same content in the `jar` variable. I provided an example cookie (`Name:Value`).

Setting the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to `true` is unnecessary because that's the property default.

Finally, the rest of the code takes each key+name pair and URL encodes it into the request body. I'll agree it is complicated and I'm surprised that `HttpWebRequest` does not come with an easy way to generate a URL-encoded request body.

Comment: Dear Dai, Thanks for your solution, I have two doubts 1) You are sending this request to https://10.71.1.111/check.shtml from where I am getting the authentication but not to https:// 10.71.1.111/UserAuthentication/AddUser.shtml  where actually the device is creating the user. Will I directly fire to https:// 10.71.1.111/UserAuthentication/AddUser.shtml  2) if I directly fire to https:// 10.71.1.111/UserAuthentication/AddUser.shtml then how will it get the cookie or it will automatically create it. I am really sorry to ask you this but I am new to it so asking the same.

Comment: I Tyied the above code but its not working on response = request.GetResponse(); its returning NULL

Comment: @SantanuDas `GetResponse` never returns null, it throws an exception when there's an error. Debug your code and watch any thrown exceptions.